# How to reduce npm bloatware by ignoring specified directories?

Tags: node.js, npm

```
node_modules/
    someLib/
        test/
        .npmignore         <- uses this one instead
        package.json
.npmignore                 <- test/ in here
package.json
```

Is there a way I can ignore that `test/`? If I try to define a `.npmignore` at the same level as `node_modules`, it just uses the one in `someLib/` instead, so `npm install someLib` ends up pulling in `test/`.

Answer (score 0):

It's up for the package authors to decide what to ignore. So, a `.npmignore` file in your application will have no effect, unless you `npm install` it.

From [the NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/all#keeping-files-out-of-your-package):

> Use a .npmignore file to keep stuff out of your package.

You can however simply ping the package author to include `test/` in `.npmignore`, or send a pull request yourself.